# How to make "+" and "*" work inside lookahead of regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am now having trouble with the regex inside lookahead inside a regex formula. For specially, given the string:

```
"hello" world
```

then the following regex seems not to work:

```
(?<=\"\w+\" )world
```

So how could the regex formula be that I could use to catch just the 'world'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in your example (`(?<=\"\w+\" )world`) is a lookbehind not a lookahead. Most languages, including PHP, do not support non-fixed length regexes in a lookbehind.

Instead you could write a regex like `\"w+\" (world)` and extract the value of the first capture group. Though with this example a regex seems to be overkill...

Comment: Yes you know, this's just a short example for my idea. So thank you with your information that <pre>Most languages, including PHP, do not support non-fixed length regexes in a lookbehind</pre>

Answer (score 1):

When I checked your regex in a regex playground, it showed some error in '?<='. Then, I changed your regex to

`(\?*<*=*"*\w+"* )world`

it matched with test case "hello" world.

The first problem you need to use '\' before '?'

The others about * and +: * require match 0 or more, + require match 1 or more. So, use * after words can be skipped, and + for words can't.

Test your regex and understand formula mean at: https://regexr.com/

Comment: You know, this is a problem with lookbehind in regex, not just playing with characters...